# Count and Foreach?

Tags: php

I am trying to count the number of rows I am selecting from the database and write a Foreach loop if the number of rows is greater than 1. I keep getting an unexpected ')' error. Why is this?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        $login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];
        echo '<h1>Welcome '. $login_session .'</h1>';
    }

    echo '<table>';
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Courses";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 1) {
        foreach($result as $row)
            echo '<tr>'. $row['Title'] .'</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';        
?>
```

The exact error is:

```
[12-Aug-2016 09:54:29 Europe/London] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/etd/public_html/etd/single/courses.php on line 33
```

Comment: You are missing the **{** after **foreach($result as $row)**

Answer (score 0):

It's unexpected `'}'` error (curly braces).

Your foreach loop is missing the opening curly brace. It should be like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        $login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];
        echo '<h1>Welcome '. $login_session .'</h1>';
    }

    echo '<table>';
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Courses";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 1) {
        foreach($result as $row) {  // this is where the curly bracket opening is missing
            echo '<tr>'. $row['Title'] .'</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';        
?>
```

Without the opening there is one extra closing curly brace and as the interpreter told you - it is unexpected.

Comment: This worked but does not write anything out.

Comment: Maybe you have only one record in your database? Notice that your if-statement condition is `$count > 1` which means that you need to have more than one record in the database to print it.

Comment: There is 90 rows in the database.

Comment: If I just use the count with no foreach loop I'll show 1 row and not all of them.

Comment: You should use mysql_fetch_array in the while loop, instead of foreach. Like this:
`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a opening curly bracket (`{`) on your foreach

Your code:

```
if($count > 1) {
    foreach($result as $row)
        echo '<tr>'. $row['Title'] .'</tr>';
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
if($count > 1) {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo '<tr>'. $row['Title'] .'</tr>';
    }
}
```

The reason it's an unexpected `}` because there isn't an opening bracket for it to match against

Answer (score 0):

Missing braces foreachloop

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
        $login_session = $_SESSION['login_user'];
        echo '<h1>Welcome '. $login_session .'</h1>';
    }

    echo '<table>';
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM Courses";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql_query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($count > 1) {
        foreach($result as $row) {
            echo '<tr>'. $row['Title'] .'</tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';        
?>
```